# Friends Referral

Tags: php

I want a PHP code to load contact list from Hotmail, Yahoo and Gmail something like a friend referral scripts.  If possible, I don't want something ready-made (except for the connection libraries).

Comment: Have you tried googling?

Comment: It's not as simple as you make it out to be.

Comment: @Kerry: tried googling, yet I can`t something of good use!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [OpenInviter](http://openinviter.com/).

Comment: is it an open source, or is it encoded?

Comment: @sikas: Open source, of course.